# Formula Fields (Date and Date/Time): Case Elapsed Duration

Tags: community, case, formula-field

Can someone help us what would be the formula for the following:

1. Elapsed date since the case was created.
2. Elapsed day and time  since the case was created.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create Text based formula field and use following formula.

> Elapsed date since the case was created.

```
IF(FLOOR( (NOW()- CreatedDate)) > 0,TEXT( FLOOR( (NOW()- CreatedDate)) ) & " days ", "")
```

It will display the value like this:

```
19 days
```

> Elapsed day and time since the case was created.

```
IF(FLOOR( (NOW()- CreatedDate)) > 0,TEXT( FLOOR( (NOW()- CreatedDate)) ) & " days ", "") 
& IF(FLOOR( MOD( (NOW()- CreatedDate)* 24, 24 ) )>0,TEXT( FLOOR( MOD( (NOW()- CreatedDate)* 24, 24 ) ) ) & " hours ","") 
& TEXT( ROUND( MOD( (NOW()- CreatedDate)* 24 * 60, 60 ), 0 ) ) & " minutes "
& TEXT( ROUND( MOD( (NOW()- CreatedDate)* 24 * 60*60, 60 ), 0 ) ) & " seconds"
```

It will display the value like this:

```
19 days 13 hours 7 minutes 53 seconds
```

Comment: hi @santanu, what if we want to remove the weekends on the date/time computation?

Comment: then better to use business hours, as formula is very fragile, you can post as separate question